# How to use route with a mounted engined in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just started using rails. I am getting into installing engines to run an app in one I have already started. I have ben trying to use forem to build a forum.
I've followed the instructions carefully but am confused by the following. I have been told to mount the engine as follows:

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :events

  resources :photos, only: [:new, :create, :index]
  root to: 'home#new'


  mount Forem::Engine, :at => "/forum"
  resources :forem 

 end
```

I then do a

```
 rake routes
```

to get the paths I should use which gives me

```
Routes for Forem::Engine:
                     root GET    /                                                        forem/forums#index
               categories GET    /categories(.:format)                                    forem/categories#index
                 category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                                forem/categories#show
               admin_root GET    /admin(.:format)                                         forem/admin/base#index
  add_admin_group_members POST   /admin/groups/:group_id/members/add(.:format)            forem/admin/members#add
       admin_group_member DELETE /admin/groups/:group_id/members/:id(.:format)            forem/admin/members#destroy
             admin_groups GET    /admin/groups(.:format)                                  forem/admin/groups#index
```

(not all shown for brevity)

so when I enter the path so I can look at the pages eg

```
 [https://railstbb-sebastiz.c9.io/forem/admin][1]
```

I get the error

```
uninitialized constant ForemController
```

so I went ahead a created a controller called forem_controller (even through there are no indications that this should be done in the instructions) and I still get the same error.

I've tried to read about routes endlessly but I really dont understand why this shouldnt work

As suggested I tried using the address as follows:

```
 https://railstbb-sebastiz.c9.io/forum/admin
```

But I get an error message saying

```
 NameError in Forem::Forums#index 
 undefined local variable or method `edit_user_registration_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd888f49ee0>:0x007fd888f48f40>
```

with the following area highlighted

```
 <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %>
```

Comment: When you `mount Forem::Engine, :at => "/forum"` your paths to that engine will all start with `/forum/` ex `https://railstbb-sebastiz.c9.io/forum/admin`

Comment: OK when I type in that URL I get an error message saying NameError in Forem::Forums#index with the following area highlighted <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |

Comment: You may want to add that to the question or make a new one for it. Lengthy code in comments gets messy.

Comment: First thought is the path should be main_app.edit_user_registration_path. This is because that path is in the main app, not the engine. However I'm not sure on that. Is there anything else in the error message?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure if its referring to the need for a controller. I've added the further error. The installation doesn't seem to have added a controller or any views! I always assumed I needed these but according to instructions this only seems to be needed for customisation

Comment: I think it may be what I mentioned, but I'm not sure. I'm not familiar with forem, or devise, but I think that those are supposed to path to Devise actions, which are in the main app, not the engine. When you link from an engine to the main app, the path needs the `main_app.<path>` so it knows where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you mounted the engine in your main app like so?

```
mount Forem::Engine, :at => "/"
```

Comment: The mount I've shown above is in the routes.rb for the main app. Do I need to put it somewhere else. Also I dont want the forem to open as the root page